# How to properly write a python function that reads keys from a separate json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a python script that will read json and look for a specific key. So far, I can get it to work if I include my json values as a variable. However, my end goal is to read the json values from a file. Here is the code that I've been working on:

```
import jwt
import os

jwks = {
  "keys": [
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "123456ABCDEF",
      "x5t": "123456ABCDEF",
      "n": "qa9f6h6h52XbX0iAgxKgEDlRpbJw",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "43aw7PQjxt4/MpfNMS2BfZ5F8GVSVG7qNb352cLLeJg5rc398Z"
      ]
    },
    {
      "kty": "RSA",
      "use": "sig",
      "kid": "987654ghijklmnoP",
      "x5t": "987654ghijklmnoP",
      "n": "qa9f6h6h52XbX0iAgxKgEDlRpbJw",
      "e": "AQAB",
      "x5c": [
        "1234R46Qjxt4/MpfNMS2BfZ5F8GVSVG7qNb352cLLeJg5rc398Z"
      ]
    } 
  ]
}


class InvalidAuthorizationToken(Exception):
    def __init__(self, details):
        super().__init__('Invalid authorization token: ' + details)


def get_jwk(kid):
    for jwk in jwks.get('keys'):
        if jwk.get('kid') == kid:
            print ('This is jwk:', jwk)
            return jwk
    raise InvalidAuthorizationToken('kid not recognized')


#Execute
get_jwk('123456ABCDEF')
get_jwk('987654ghijklmnoP')
```

Here, what I am trying to do is replace those same values and store them in a separate file (jwks-keys) and read it in as a variable. However, I'm getting the following error and don't understand what i've done. How do I properly construct this function?

Here's the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "printjwks2.py", line 59, in <module>
    get_jwk('123456ABCDEF')
  File "printjwks2.py", line 51, in get_jwk
    for jwk in jwks.get('keys'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here's the function:

```
def get_jwk(kid):
    with open('testkeys/jwks-keys', 'r') as az:
        jwks = az.read()
    for jwk in jwks.get('keys'):
        if jwk.get('kid') == kid:
            print (jwk)
            return jwk
    raise InvalidAuthorizationToken('kid not recognized')
```

Comment: Your first `jwks` is a dict. When you read something from a file, it’s just a string. Do you want to JSON-decode it perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('testkeys/jwks-keys', 'r') as az:
        jwks = az.read()
```

Here `jwks` is just a string object because `az.read()` returns it as a string . So you have to Deserialize the JSON data into python objects before applying `jwks.get('keys')`.

```
>>> sample_json = '{"json_key": "json_value"}'
>>> sample_json.get("json_key")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(sample_json).get("json_key")
'json_value'
```

Since you are reading JSON from a file, you can use [`json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) to deserialize `fp` (a .read()-supporting text file or binary file containing a JSON document) to a Python object

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('testkeys/jwks-keys', 'r') as az:
...    jwks = json.load(az)
```